In React Native props data is not accessible, or corrupted, from function but OK in useEffect - not sure why
In one React Native component I include another comonent in JSX and I pass a props variable.
In the child component I can access the props value via the props object.
If I have multiple child components included then in the child component, which the props valid is readable fine in the userEffect function if I try to access that same props value in another function it's either null or it holds the value of a different sibling/child component which is really really weird.
e.g. Parent component: -
<>
  <SubComponent key={ 100 } myvalue= { 100} />
  <SubComponent key={ 200 } myvalue= { 200} />
</>

Child Component:
const SubComponent: React.FunctionalComponent = (props: Object) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('myvalue = '+props.myvalue);
    _runMyFunction();
  });

  _runMyFunction = async () => {
    console.log('myvalue now = '+props.myvalue); // PROBLEM IS HERE VALUE MAY BE WRONG
  };
};
export default SubComponent;

Above, in the _runMyFunction function, the props.myvalue may not be the same as it was in the useEffect (actually I'm finding that it's the last value of all instances of SubComponent in the parent component so in my log output I'll see 2 X "myvalue now = 200".
I'm not sure why I'm having this issue.  It's like some global cross-talk between the instances of the SubComponent and I didn't think that could happen.
The above is a cut-down version of my component / sub-component.
thanks for any thoughts / advice
Derek

When you create a variable without var/let/const, it's implicitly made a global variable. That means that every time you create a <SubComponent /> instance you're updating the single global _runMyFunction to point to the last _runMyFunction that was defined. Never create variables without var/let or const, otherwise you'll run into unexpected issues like this one. In fact, strict-mode code will throw an error if you try and declare variables like this (that includes in modules, classes, and functions marked with the "use strict" directive) Here's an example on how you can fix your code:
const SubComponent: React.FunctionalComponent = (props: Object) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('myvalue = '+props.myvalue);
    _runMyFunction();
  });
  
  // v--- use `const` or `let` or `var`
  const _runMyFunction = async () => {
    console.log('myvalue now = '+props.myvalue);
  };
};

Using const/let/var will make the _runMyFunction local to your SubComponent function, avoiding the implicit global variable that was being created before. It is surprising to me that your code didn't throw an error, as typically React Native code is written inside of ES Modules, which wouldn't allow this behaviour.

Thank you VERY much - this was the problem and I understand now!  I looked at this problem for about 5 hours !
